# Sharepoint 2013 Managed Properties in Search Template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, managed-property

I have a Sharepoint 2013 search display template working nicely. I wanted to add a new managed property mapping to the template which is of type "hyperlink or picture". This content type stores both a URL and description. It returns a comma separated value of link and description (ie. http://www.yahoo.com, my description). Not sure how to grab the link and description individually using $getItemValue from within the template?

Any pointers or examples would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From within the template you could get the value then split it using a JavaScript function e.g.

```
var commaSeparatedLinkAndDescription = ctx.CurrentItem.MyCustomProperty;

if(commaSeparatedLinkAndDescription){
     var array = commaSeparatedLinkAndDescription.split(','); 
}
```

Then assign the first and second array elements to variables for the URL and description.

```
var URL = array[0];
var Description = array[1];
```

Hope this helps!